# Starting my Topology with Storm 2.2.0 : Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [localhost]

Tags: java, apache-storm, configuration-files

I'm working with storm 2.2.0 and my configuration file is:

```
#storm.yaml
storm.local.hostname: "10.100.7.109"

storm.zookeeper.servers:
    - "10.100.242.107"

nimbus.seeds: ["localhost"]

supervisor.slots.ports:    
    - 6701
    - 6702
    - 6703
    - 6704
    - 6705
    - 6706
    - 6707
    - 6708
    - 6709
    - 6710
    - 6711
    - 6712
    - 6713
    - 6714
    - 6715
    - 6716    
    - 6717
```

The storm nimbus work correctly but when starting one topology i have an error related with `nimbus.seeds` configuration:

```
    20:58:05.488 [main] WARN  o.a.s.v.ConfigValidation - task.heartbeat.frequency.secs is a deprecated config please see class org.apache.storm.Config.TASK_HEARTBEAT_FREQUENCY_SECS for more information.
    20:58:05.563 [main] WARN  o.a.s.u.NimbusClient - Ignoring exception while trying to get leader nimbus info from localhost. will retry with a different seed host.
    org.apache.storm.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing getLeader
    ...
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [localhost]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
```

When running the command `storm list`, I receive the same error:

```
root@storm-nimbus-60:/usr/share/storm-2.2.0/conf# storm list
Running: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -client -Ddaemon.name= -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/usr/share/storm-2.2.0 -Dstorm.log.dir=/usr/share/storm-2.2.0/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64 -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /usr/share/storm-2.2.0/*:/usr/share/storm-2.2.0/lib/*:/usr/share/storm-2.2.0/extlib/*:/usr/share/storm-2.2.0/extlib-daemon/*:/usr/share/storm-2.2.0/conf:/usr/share/storm-2.2.0/bin org.apache.storm.command.ListTopologies
21:09:39.153 [main] INFO  o.a.s.v.ConfigValidation - Will use [class org.apache.storm.DaemonConfig, class org.apache.storm.Config] for validation
21:09:39.438 [main] WARN  o.a.s.v.ConfigValidation - task.heartbeat.frequency.secs is a deprecated config please see class org.apache.storm.Config.TASK_HEARTBEAT_FREQUENCY_SECS for more information.
21:09:39.669 [main] WARN  o.a.s.u.NimbusClient - Ignoring exception while trying to get leader nimbus info from localhost. will retry with a different seed host.
org.apache.storm.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing getLeader
    at org.apache.storm.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:79) ~[storm-shaded-deps-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.recv_getLeader(Nimbus.java:1183) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.getLeader(Nimbus.java:1171) ~[storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:222) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:179) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.withConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:127) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.withConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:117) [storm-client-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.apache.storm.command.ListTopologies.main(ListTopologies.java:27) [storm-core-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusLeaderNotFoundException: Could not find leader nimbus from seed hosts [localhost]. Did you specify a valid list of nimbus hosts for config nimbus.seeds?
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:250)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:179)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.withConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.withConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:117)
    at org.apache.storm.command.ListTopologies.main(ListTopologies.java:27)
```

Any solutions for my errors? Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error looks like you haven't any nimbus service running.
It happens also if the nimbus can't connect to the zookeeper server.
Apache Storm 2.2.0 required a zookeeper service, even your run it locally.
I recommend you to run these services locally for easy development and debug:

- zookeeper
- storm supervisor
- storm nimbus
- storm UI

My storm.yaml is:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
 - "127.0.0.1"

storm.local.dir: "/opt/apache-storm-1.2.2/data/"
nimbus.host: "127.0.0.1" # for nimbus
nimbus.seeds: ["localhost"] # for ui and supervisor
supervisor.slots.ports:
 - 6700   # no need to more than one topology running

supervisor.memory.capacity.mb: 8192.0 #i have 16G ram, half for storm
supervisor.cpu.capacity: 600.0 # and 6 core cpu
# your storm dashboard will be at http://localhost:8081/
ui.port: 8081
ui.host: "0.0.0.0"
```